# Saving data to a txt file using a for loop in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to save data to a `.txt` file using a condition `len(J[i+1])>=len(J[i])`. But I am getting an error. How do I fix this? Basically, I want the code to save the data only when the condition is met, not otherwise i.e. selective saving (if such a term exists).

```
File=1
import csv
for i in range(0,5):
    J=[0,1]*(i-1)
    print("J =",J)
    print("len J =",len(J))
    
    with open(rf"C:\Users\User\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Surfactant A-D\12 nodes_New\{File}\Test.txt", 'a') as f: 
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        if (len(J[i+1])>=len(J[i])): 
            f.writelines('\n')
            f.write(str(J))
```

The error is

```
 in <module>
    if (len(J[i+1])>=len(J[i])):

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: For `i < 2` `J` will be an empty list. `J[i+1]` and `J[i]` will raise this error.

Comment: Your problem is not about writing files. It's about accessing a list with an out-of-range index. Please, adjust the question title accordingly.

Comment: Your list has `n` items, and you try to access the `n+1`th item. How do you think that's going to work?

Answer (score 0):

`J=[0,1]*(i-1)` creates a list like so `[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]`. your code later checks `if (len(J[i+1])>=len(J[i])):`  but your list is flat so you can not get length of the value there. (this will be a future error)

the reason you get the error is the first value of i-1 is 0 so you create an empty list with `J=[0,1]*(i-1)` where there is no values to compare. try multiplying it just by i

Answer (score 0):

This will throw an error because you in this line

`if (len(J[i+1])>=len(J[i])):`

you are trying to access the j[5] in the fifth iteration of the loop. And Since j[5] doesn't exist it throws an error.

trying modifying your code in such a way that it won't try to access the element which is not present in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an approch like this

```
def save_data_to_txt(J):
    # Assuming J is a list of strings

    with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
        # Iterate over the elements of J, except the last one
        for i in range(len(J) - 1):
            if len(J[i+1]) >= len(J[i]):
                # Write the current element to the file
                file.write(J[i] + '\n')

        # Write the last element of J unconditionally
        file.write(J[-1] + '\n')
```